# Type Error when drilling down into a type

Tags: typescript, types

I have types like below

```
export type DataType = {
  id: string;
  type: string;
  'product-configuration': { inputs: ConfigurationType };
};

export type ConfigurationType = {
  [key: string]: ItemDataType;
};

export type ItemDataType = {
  required: boolean;
  type: string;
  hint?: string;
  constraint?: ConstraintType;
  options?: string[];
  conditional?: ConditionalItemDataType;
};

export type ConstraintType = {
  min?: number;
  max?: number;
  format?: string;
};

export type ConditionalItemType = [
  { condition: string },
  { [key: string]: ItemDataType }
];

export type ConditionalItemDataType = ConditionalItemType[];
```

Then I have a object that meets this type

```
const abc = {
  id: 45,
  type: 'product',
  'product-configuration': {
    inputs: {
      'Instance Name': {
        required: true,
        type: 'text',
        constraint: {
          min: 3,
          max: 15,
          format: 'alpha-hyphen-numeric',
        },
      },
      Environment: {
        required: true,
        type: 'select',
        options: ['Prod', 'Dev'],
      },
      'Content Type': {
        required: true,
        type: 'select',
        options: ['Markdown', 'HTML'],
        conditional: [
          [
            { condition: 'Markdown' },
            {
              'Folder Location': {
                required: true,
                type: 'text',
                constraint: {
                  max: 30,
                },
              },
            },
          ],
        ],
      },
      'Content folder path': {
        required: false,
        type: 'select',
        options: ['Root', 'Content'],
      },
      'Start Date': {
        required: true,
        type: 'date',
      },
      'Need Playground': {
        required: false,
        type: 'select',
        options: ['Yes', 'No'],
      },
    },
  },
};
```

I want to get the `keys` of all the objects that have the key `required` inside them.

For that I have the below code

```
const findFieldNames = (obj, result = [], currentPath = '') => {
  for (const key in obj) {    
    const newPath = currentPath ? `${currentPath}.${key}` : key;
    if (typeof obj[key] === 'object') {
          findFieldNames(obj[key], result, newPath);
    } else if (key === 'required') {
      result.push(newPath.match(/(?<=\.)([^.]+)(?=\.required$)/)[0]);
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

This code works fine in `JS` however in TS, I get type errors  as shown in the pic below

[image]

I am able to eliminate the first error by changing `typeof obj[key] === 'object'` to `typeof obj[key as keyof DataType] === 'object'` but I am not able to get rid of the other 2 errors.

If is use `obj: any` instead of `obj: DataType` , then the first 2 errors are gone but the 3rd on still persists. However, I do not want to use `any`.

How to get rid of these type errors? Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, store the result of `obj[key as keyof DataType]` in a separate variable. TypeScript isn't smart enough to understand that `FindFieldNames(obj[key as keyof DataType])` should work even after passing the `typeof` type guard.

```
let val = obj[key as keyof DataType];
if (typeof val === 'object') {
  findFieldNames(val, result, newPath);
}
```

Once you do that, you'll get another error complaining that `'{ inputs: ConfigurationType; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'DataType'`, right? That's because something is wrong with your typing. `FindFieldNames()` accepts an object of type `DataType` for the `obj` parameter, but none of the properties on `DataType` are of type `DataType` (they're either type `string` or type `{inputs: Configuration}`), so you can't pass `obj[key as keyof DataType]` to `FindFieldNames()`. If you want `FindFieldNames()` to accept more types for the first parameter, you need to broaden the type annotation. Perhaps you meant to annotate `obj` as a union type of all those different types you defined at the top (including `{inputs: ConfigurationType}`, which you didn't create a separate type for for some reason); I can't tell.

The last error is a quick fix. `String.prototype.match()` returns an array if matches are found or `null` if no matches are found, so TypeScript can't be sure that you're pushing something valid. Just store the match result in a separate variable and then wrap the `push()` in an if-statement that checks to see if the match is `null`.

```
const matchResult = newPath.match(/(?<=\.)([^.]+)(?=\.required$)/);
if (matchResult) {
  result.push((matchResult[0])); // no error
}
```